# QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonality

Assuming that we have a QR decomposition of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $Q \in O(m)$ and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $A=QR$, where R is an upper triangular matrix.

Now the question is if we have a new matrix $\overline {A} = \begin{pmatrix} w^T \\A \end{pmatrix}$, where $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the question is. How can we build an orthogonal matrix $\overline{Q} \in O(m+1)$ from that such that $\overline {A} = \overline {Q} \overline {R}$ is another QR decomposition.

My idea was that

$\begin{pmatrix} 10-0 \\0 Q^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} w^T \\A \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} w^T \\R \end{pmatrix}$, so the question is equivalent to: How do we make a proper triangular matrix out of $ \begin{pmatrix} w^T \\R \end{pmatrix}$ by applying orthogonal matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix 
$$\tag{1}
X=\begin{bmatrix}w^T\\R\end{bmatrix}
$$
is upper [Hessenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix). If $R\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, you can make (1) triangular by using $n$ Givens rotations (from left). Use the first Givens rotation to zero out the entry $(2,1)$ of $X$ by using row 1. Note that only rows 1 and 2 are modified. The next rotations acts on the rows 2 and 3 and zeroes out the entry (3,2). Continue this way on subsequent rows until the sub-diagonal entries are zero. This can update the QR factorisation using $O(n^2)$ operations.

See also the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation#Triangularization).